# How to reduce the number of cookies?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, cookies, internet-explorer-8

I am creating webpage for some list. My webpage always runs from DVD only (locally) no web server and domain.

I have to use IE8 or IE9 as browser so I am not able to use newer browsers.

I have more than 135 checkboxes and I want to store cookies for each checkboxes state. However, IE8 can store only 50 cookies.

So my program works very fine up to 50 cookies but when I add more cookies it stops responding.

So how I can reduce number of cookies? I am using carhartl’s jQuery Cookies ui. Can I group some cookies using JSON or other technology?

Comment: You can put more than 1 thing in 1 cookie, E.g. quick and dirty 135 characters comprising "101010100011..." to indicate state.

Comment: Just answered a very similar question. Cookies shouldn't be used for this, use localStorage  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31457033/javascript-checkbox-cookie/31457169#31457169

Comment: as for using json..yes you can but keep in mind that cookies also have size limits. All the extra quotes in json could be problematic if you get close to those limits. A lot of people will use a simple delimiter like `|` to join and parse an array

Comment: Thank you friends now i use JSON and it works fine for me. But i find that using Store.js is much better. Black thanks for editing.